# slideToggle not working with button activation

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I've stripped away all the CSS and extra HTML and left a bare bones jsFiddle which demonstrates my failure to get this to work: http://jsfiddle.net/95vme63e/

```
<div class="sectionHeader1"> 
  <div>
    <p class="sectionTitle"> 1: Description </p> 
    <button type="button" class="sectionButton questioner">Button</button>
    <div class="questions">
      <ul>
        <li> Question one </li>
        <li> Question two </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>

$(".questioner").on("click", function () {
  $(".questions").slideToggle(500);
});

.sectionHeader1 .questions {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I want to click a button which toggles whether a set of questions is visible.
Currently, clicking that button seemingly does nothing.
Originally I had a lot of CSS and extra HTML elements and thought this must be contributing but I've removed pretty much everything I thought to be non-essential and the problem persists.

If anyone could point out my mistake or offer any advice that would be great,
Thanks!

Comment: The fiddle works fine if you include jQuery in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your problem is that you have not included jQuery.

See example:

```js
$(".questioner").on("click", function () {
  $(".questions").slideToggle(500);
});
```

```css
.sectionHeader1 .questions {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionHeader1"> 
  <div>
    <p class="sectionTitle"> 1: Description </p> 
    <button type="button" class="sectionButton questioner">Button</button>
    <div class="questions">
      <ul>
        <li> Question one </li>
        <li> Question two </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The error is

[image]

Which is revealed by looking at the console log (In developer tools)

Include jQuery by putting this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in either the `<head>` tag or the `<body>` tag and it should will work flawlessly.

```js
$(".questioner").on("click", function () {
  $(".questions").slideToggle(500);
});
```

```css
.sectionHeader1 .questions {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sectionHeader1"> 
  <div>
    <p class="sectionTitle"> 1: Description </p> 
    <button type="button" class="sectionButton questioner">Button</button>
    <div class="questions">
      <ul>
        <li> Question one </li>
        <li> Question two </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

using `toggle`

and add `jquery` library

```js
$(".sectionButton").on("click", function() {
  $(".questions").toggle();
});
```

```css
.sectionHeader1 .questions {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sectionHeader1">
  <div>
    <p class="sectionTitle"> 1: Description </p>
    <button type="button" class="sectionButton questioner">Button</button>
    <div class="questions">
      <ul>
        <li> Question one </li>
        <li> Question two </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```